# Sandboxing and directory listing

Tags: cocoa, macos, sandbox, nsfilemanager, osx-lion

A common task I do consists reading a directory content using NSFileManager:contentsOfDirectoryAtPath but enabling sandboxing in Lion this becomes impossible.

I know user must choose from a NSOpenPanel the directory to make Sandbox happy (or dropping it) but how can I "inform" sandbox that I must read directory from a path previously stored in some configuration file without user interaction?

Currently I've set the following entitlement keys

```
com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write
com.apple.security.documents.user-selected.read-write
com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sandbox currently doesn't remember what's it allowed to access on the file system between application launches.

This is tracked at Apple at some high-priority radar but I still suggest that you file your own bug report as well, to raise its awareness even higher within Apple.

Comment: @twickl Yes, it is solved since 10.7.3. But it requires special code from you. Basically, it means you have to convert your URLs to Secure Bookmarks (as opposed to regular URL bookmarks) and these can be saved and used in the application. There are two types of secure bookmarks - per app (saved between launches for the whole app) or per-document, for cases where the document refers to other files, such as a project document that references other file resources. Check out Apple's documentation on NSURL to learn about secure bookmarks.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! I will check the document